# Vertically center input form in table Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, vertical-alignment, bootstrap-modal

I can't vertically center input form in table using Twitter Bootstrap. I've found solution on the stack but it works only with plain text, doesn't work with input form (class vert-align). Do you have any suggestions?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4urJT/10/)

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                      <th>
                       #
                      </th>
                      <th>
                       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i>
                      </th>
                      <th>
                      Item#1
                      </th>
                      <th>
                      Item#2
                      </th>
                     </tr>
        <div class="row">
          <tr>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <td class="vert-align">
                1
              </td>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <td class="vert-align">
            <input type="checkbox">
              </td>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <td class="vert-align">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="...">
              </div>
            </div>
              </td>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <td class="vert-align">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="...">
              </div>
            </div>
              </td>
            </div>
          </tr>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <tr>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <td class="vert-align">
              2
              </td>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <td class="vert-align">
            <input type="checkbox">
              </td>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="...">
              </div>
            </div>
              </td>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="...">
              </div>
            </div>
              </td>
            </div>
          </tr>
        </div>
      </table>
```

and css

```
 .datepicker.dropdown-menu {
z-index: 1151;
  }

  .table tbody>tr>td.vert-align {
vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

Comment: Do you want your modal form vertically center of screen or input box text vertically center? can you please create your fiddle and link here so can understand what you want properly.

Comment: @Nimmi I've refreshed question, deleted unnecessary modal. I just want to center input forms vertically the same as eg numbers but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please update this CSS
.vert-align .form-group { margin-bottom: auto; } 
Hope this will solve your problem :)

Comment: when I do this vertical center doesn't work on numbers:( @Nimmi

Comment: Actually form-group has bottom margin but if you want more spacing than I think you should use top margin too. I have updated fiddle please see : http://jsfiddle.net/4urJT/12/

Comment: hope this is what you are looking for..